# Renewal process: find the distribution based on percentages

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution, renewal-processes

I was trying to solve the following renewal process problem:

> A policeman spends his entire day on the lookout for speeders. The
> policeman cruises on average approximately 10 minutes before stopping
> a car for some offense. Of the cars he stops, 90% of the drivers are
> given speeding tickets with an \$80 fine. It takes the policeman an
> average of 5 minutes to write such a ticket. The other 10% of the
> stops are for more serious offenses, leading to an average fine of
> \$300. These more serious charges take an average of 30 minutes to
> process. Let's suppose we start to observe the policeman when he
> finishes writing a ticket.
>
> Suppose that the time the policeman takes is exactly 10 minutes, from
> the time he finishes fining one car until he stops the next car and
> the time that it takes to process the fine is uniform, with the lower
> bound being 0 (both minor and serious offenses)
>
> 1 - What would be the the distribution of the time that elapses since
> the policeman ends with a car until the next fine is processed?
>
> 2 - What is the distribution of the number of fines processed in 1
> hour would (from the beginning)?

But I found some problems to give the distribution in an explicit manner.

Until the moment I have:

$$f(z) = \begin{cases}
U(10, 15) & \text{for 90% of the cases} \\
U(10, 40) & \text{for 10% of the cases} \\
\end{cases}$$

And from there, I was looking [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/418558/728632) to calculate the sum of the two distributions. But

- How can I deal with the percentages?
- In case this can not be given as a explicit formula, how can I calculate the last part of the exercise (2)?

Comment: $f(z) = 0.9 U(10, 15) + 0.1U(10, 40)$. It follows immediately from total probability theorem.